# How to read the ReturnUrl query parameter from Loginpage in my MVC 3 controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, forms-authentication

I have this url in my login page:
http://localhost:5550/login?ReturnUrl=/forum/456

I have this controller:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Try(LoginModel model){
   //How can I read the ReturnURL query string parameter and other params inside my controller?

//what is the recommended way to do this?
}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`?

That should give your your host's URL.

EDIT: Seems you changed your post's question!

I'm not sure this is what you want but to get the ReturnUrl part in your controller, you can pass the string ReturnUrl to your controller for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Try(LoginModel model, string ReturnUrl)
{
    // bla bla bla
}
```

You'll get the "/forum/456" as a string.

Comment: I don't have access to that. What namespace or inheritance do I need?

Comment: @user - please click the checkbox next to this answer if it works for you

Comment: I just can't accept this as answer yet. Login page has a url with a query string ?ReturnUrl=/xyz/abc How do I read this query parameter in my controller?

Comment: Edited my answer from your new question.